# I am trying to capture and save a video file by Open-CV but it's not playing

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

here is my code which i tried. video file is creating after the code run but video file is not playing. i have trouble to understand?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') 

out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/DarkLord/Downloads/output1.avi',fourcc, 20,(1920,1000))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    if ret==True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It might help

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/DarkLord/Downloads/output1.avi',fourcc, 20,(1920,1000))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/DarkLord/Downloads/output1.avi', -1, 20,(1920,1000))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explained what you changed and why you think that'll help.

Comment: it's not working. my webcam is activated when i run this code but cv2.imshow is not working and output is not also generating.

Answer (score 0):

The size of your video must be the same as the size of your camera reading frame.
Fix the code like this.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
out = cv2.VideoWriter(r'C:/Users/DarkLord/Downloads/output1.avi',fourcc, 20,size)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    if ret==True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```